# Какие есть актуальные способы для работы с wi-fi сетями в python?

Tags: python, wifi, модули

Какие есть актуальные способы для работы с wi-fi сетями в python под windows? Интересуют модули по которым легко найти документацию

Comment: Платформа? Линукс, виндовс?

Comment: @eri под виндовс